# How to upload images from remix to sanity.io?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multipartform-data, sanity, remix.run

I am trying to upload images from a remix app to sanity.io from a server action where I am sending data through form submit using encode type `multipart/formData`.

I cannot understand how to parse the file correctly from `formData` to send to sanity.

I have looked at [`unstable_parseMultipartFormData`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#unstable_parsemultipartformdata) and am using the following code for the main upload:

```js
 const imageAsset = await sanityClient.assets.upload(
      'image',
      // <not sure what to put here>,
      {
        contentType: profilePic.type,
        filename: `${name}-profile-pic`,
      }
    );

    const sanityDoc = {
      _type: 'profilePic',
      image: {
        _type: 'image',
        asset: {
          _type: 'reference',
          _ref: imageAsset._id,
        },
      },
      name,
      email,
      isOrganisation: false,
    };

    await sanityClient.create(sanityDoc);
```

Thanks for the help!